# wrong hash pasted after copying on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hashing

well i don't know how to explain it but always when i copy some hash from any hashin like base64 sha256 md5 etc even a txid of Bitcoin or Ethereum or Denarius my Windows 10 copy always paste wrong hash
example i copy this txid : `73f3bd963b93833c28be3cec2d133114dedb09b2873293dd0000ba663034564d` from an altcoin cryptocurrency it copies `732n3AfVM36ugBczzdtwkxC6Rai1so3ajf973293dd0000ba663034564d` which is not the correct hash it happens with almost all hashes and i dont know what is happening i always have to copy and paste the hash by parts any idea? do i have to change system?

another example is this one sha256 hash i get `2d8c2f6d978ca21712b5f6de36c9d31fa8e96a4fa5d8ff8b0188dfb9e7c171bb` but my Windows 10 copies `2d8c2f6d978ca232n3AfVM36ugBczzdtwkxC6Rai1so3ajf9b9e7c171bb` which makes it unusable
sorry if someone already asked it but since i dont know what is causing this i don't know how to start searching

**EDIT 1**

how i hash?
for the txid  Bitcoin or Ethereum or any altcoin generates its hashes from it's daemon
for base64 md5 sha256 or any type of hashing i use some sites that is working for me in linux but not on my copy of windows it happens only on my computer but not on my father's computer which is an old computer
the site i used for hashing sha256 was https://md5decrypt.net/en/Sha256/#answer which if i paste the working hash Windows pastes a bad hash which doesn't work
but if i paste the hash by parts it works like a charm

**EDIT 2**

i uploaded a video to youtube of what i mean so you can understand better what happens here is the [link](https://youtu.be/DVG8rdVUZEw) to it

Comment: i updated with a video to help you understand what is happening

Comment: Run malware/virus scans. I've read about some that will monitor the clipboard and replace copied cryptocurrency addresses.

Comment: omg will try right now

Comment: @kicken you saved my life!!!!!!!! https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/32n3AfVM36ugBczzdtwkxC6Rai1so3ajf9 it was that virus you said! thanks a lot i thought it were my windows copy thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to [@kicken](https://superuser.com/users/515238/kicken) that warned me about virus that monitor clipboard for cryptoaddresses and replace them by criminals owned address now i'm clean and i can copy hashes freely with no problems

this is the [source](https://www.pcrisk.com/removal-guides/15815-clipboard-hijacker-malware#:%7E:text=Clipboard%20Hijacker%20is%20malicious%20software,others%20owned%20by%20cyber%20criminals.) where i got more information about that virus